# Omnet++ 5.0 and inet framework installation problems

Tags: omnet++, inet

What's the right way to install omnet++ 5.0 and inet framework on windows 7 64bit OS. I want to work with them for my thesis. I have been having issues with the installations. I have never used omnet before this is my first shot at it.

Answer (score 1):

I am running OMNeT++ 5.0 on win7 x64 without any problems.

Just download the windows version on the website [OMNeT++](https://omnetpp.org/omnetpp)
and follow the instructions in ..\omnetpp-5.0\doc\InstallGuide.pdf in chapter 2.

In case of any problems, I suggest you ask again in a more specific way.

Comment: Omnet is working just fine. My problem is with the Inet framework, I have installed it but I can't run the simulation samples that come with it,

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some info what kind of issues you have. Saying that you have issues does not help much diagnosing them. (error messages, logs, which example you have tried would help a lot).

Comment: The problem is when I tried running the simulation samples, it will say 'simulation encountered a problem' and I am having building errors as well .. the errors in details are... invalid project path, include path not found, fatal error, the omnet++ IDEnative library failed to load, all omnet related functionality will be unaccessible., UnsatisfiedLinkError no opplibs in java.library.path

Comment: checkmakefiles error, recipe for target 'checkmakefiles failed'... This are errors am getting when trying to build the Inet project

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem. Its from the windows extracting tool. I extracted omnet using 7zip archiver and now everything works fine